# Java Spring Shell hot-swap issue - misread input

Tags: java, spring, shell

I'm quite new to Java and Spring in general. I've tried to add dev tools to gradle config:
developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
and ticked the "Build project automatically" in intellij IDEA.

All works fine until I try to use shell command.

When it first starts shell reads my input fine:

```
shell:>help
AVAILABLE COMMANDS

Built-In Commands
       help: Display help about available commands
       stacktrace: Display the full stacktrace of the last error.
       clear: Clear the shell screen.
       quit, exit: Exit the shell.
       history: Display or save the history of previously run commands
       version: Show version info
       script: Read and execute commands from a file.

Security Commands
       import-quote:
```

However after the hot reload you I see a different picture:

```
2023-12-31T00:22:12.387Z  INFO 35799 --- [  restartedMain] c.i.investorapi.InvestorapiApplication   : Starting InvestorapiApplication using Java 21.0.1 with PID 35799 
2023-12-31T00:22:12.387Z  INFO 35799 --- [  restartedMain] c.i.investorapi.InvestorapiApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-12-31T00:22:12.481Z  INFO 35799 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data MongoDB repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-12-31T00:22:12.486Z  INFO 35799 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 4 ms. Found 1 MongoDB repository interface.
2023-12-31T00:22:12.528Z  INFO 35799 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2023-12-31T00:22:12.529Z  INFO 35799 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-12-31T00:22:12.529Z  INFO 35799 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.16]
2023-12-31T00:22:12.535Z  INFO 35799 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-12-31T00:22:12.535Z  INFO 35799 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 147 ms
2023-12-31T00:22:12.545Z  INFO 35799 --- [  restartedMain] org.mongodb.driver.client                : MongoClient with metadata {"driver": {"name": "mongo-java-driver|sync|spring-boot", "version": "4.11.1"}, "os": {"type": "Darwin", "name": "Mac OS X", "architecture": "aarch64", "version": "14.2.1"}, "platform": "Java/Oracle Corporation/21.0.1+12-29"} created with settings MongoClientSettings{readPreference=primary, writeConcern=WriteConcern{w=null, wTimeout=null ms, journal=null}, retryWrites=true, retryReads=true, readConcern=ReadConcern{level=null}, credential=null, transportSettings=null, streamFactoryFactory=null, commandListeners=[], codecRegistry=ProvidersCodecRegistry{codecProviders=[ValueCodecProvider{}, BsonValueCodecProvider{}, DBRefCodecProvider{}, DBObjectCodecProvider{}, DocumentCodecProvider{}, CollectionCodecProvider{}, IterableCodecProvider{}, MapCodecProvider{}, GeoJsonCodecProvider{}, GridFSFileCodecProvider{}, Jsr310CodecProvider{}, JsonObjectCodecProvider{}, BsonCodecProvider{}, EnumCodecProvider{}, com.mongodb.client.model.mql.ExpressionCodecProvider@570a645e, com.mongodb.Jep395RecordCodecProvider@20ec92f8, com.mongodb.KotlinCodecProvider@4b527fc6]}, loggerSettings=LoggerSettings{maxDocumentLength=1000}, clusterSettings={hosts=[localhost:27017], srvServiceName=mongodb, mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, requiredReplicaSetName='null', serverSelector='null', clusterListeners='[]', serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', localThreshold='15 ms'}, socketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=0, receiveBufferSize=0, proxySettings=ProxySettings{host=null, port=null, username=null, password=null}}, heartbeatSocketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=10000, receiveBufferSize=0, proxySettings=ProxySettings{host=null, port=null, username=null, password=null}}, connectionPoolSettings=ConnectionPoolSettings{maxSize=100, minSize=0, maxWaitTimeMS=120000, maxConnectionLifeTimeMS=0, maxConnectionIdleTimeMS=0, maintenanceInitialDelayMS=0, maintenanceFrequencyMS=60000, connectionPoolListeners=[], maxConnecting=2}, serverSettings=ServerSettings{heartbeatFrequencyMS=10000, minHeartbeatFrequencyMS=500, serverListeners='[]', serverMonitorListeners='[]'}, sslSettings=SslSettings{enabled=false, invalidHostNameAllowed=false, context=null}, applicationName='null', compressorList=[], uuidRepresentation=JAVA_LEGACY, serverApi=null, autoEncryptionSettings=null, dnsClient=null, inetAddressResolver=null, contextProvider=null}
2023-12-31T00:22:12.546Z  INFO 35799 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=21, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=1435625}
2023-12-31T00:22:12.550Z  INFO 35799 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2023-12-31T00:22:12.645Z  WARN 35799 --- [  restartedMain] org.jline                                : Unable to create a system terminal, creating a dumb terminal (enable debug logging for more information)
2023-12-31T00:22:12.671Z  INFO 35799 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-12-31T00:22:12.673Z  INFO 35799 --- [  restartedMain] c.i.investorapi.InvestorapiApplication   : Started InvestorapiApplication in 0.298 seconds (process running for 107.051)



shell:>help
No command found for 'hl'
shell:>help
No command found for 'ephl'
shell:>help
No command found for 'ephl'
shell:>help
No command found for 'ephl'
```

I tried restarting, waiting some time after I typed "help" - no change.
Any idea why is this happening ?
I'm on Mac, java 21.

I tried rebuilding gradle and enabling debug.
This is how it looks with debug enabled:

```
2023-12-31T11:54:10.956Z  INFO 36867 --- [  restartedMain] c.i.investorapi.InvestorapiApplication   : Starting InvestorapiApplication using Java 21.0.1 with PID 36867 ()
2023-12-31T11:54:10.957Z  INFO 36867 --- [  restartedMain] c.i.investorapi.InvestorapiApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-12-31T11:54:11.042Z  INFO 36867 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data MongoDB repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-12-31T11:54:11.047Z  INFO 36867 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 4 ms. Found 1 MongoDB repository interface.
2023-12-31T11:54:11.086Z  INFO 36867 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2023-12-31T11:54:11.087Z  INFO 36867 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-12-31T11:54:11.087Z  INFO 36867 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.16]
2023-12-31T11:54:11.094Z  INFO 36867 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-12-31T11:54:11.094Z  INFO 36867 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 136 ms
2023-12-31T11:54:11.105Z  INFO 36867 --- [  restartedMain] org.mongodb.driver.client                : MongoClient with metadata {"driver": {"name": "mongo-java-driver|sync|spring-boot", "version": "4.11.1"}, "os": {"type": "Darwin", "name": "Mac OS X", "architecture": "aarch64", "version": "14.2.1"}, "platform": "Java/Oracle Corporation/21.0.1+12-29"} created with settings MongoClientSettings{readPreference=primary, writeConcern=WriteConcern{w=null, wTimeout=null ms, journal=null}, retryWrites=true, retryReads=true, readConcern=ReadConcern{level=null}, credential=null, transportSettings=null, streamFactoryFactory=null, commandListeners=[], codecRegistry=ProvidersCodecRegistry{codecProviders=[ValueCodecProvider{}, BsonValueCodecProvider{}, DBRefCodecProvider{}, DBObjectCodecProvider{}, DocumentCodecProvider{}, CollectionCodecProvider{}, IterableCodecProvider{}, MapCodecProvider{}, GeoJsonCodecProvider{}, GridFSFileCodecProvider{}, Jsr310CodecProvider{}, JsonObjectCodecProvider{}, BsonCodecProvider{}, EnumCodecProvider{}, com.mongodb.client.model.mql.ExpressionCodecProvider@6aacf3e3, com.mongodb.Jep395RecordCodecProvider@146fffd6, com.mongodb.KotlinCodecProvider@50094c97]}, loggerSettings=LoggerSettings{maxDocumentLength=1000}, clusterSettings={hosts=[localhost:27017], srvServiceName=mongodb, mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, requiredReplicaSetName='null', serverSelector='null', clusterListeners='[]', serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', localThreshold='15 ms'}, socketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=0, receiveBufferSize=0, proxySettings=ProxySettings{host=null, port=null, username=null, password=null}}, heartbeatSocketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=10000, receiveBufferSize=0, proxySettings=ProxySettings{host=null, port=null, username=null, password=null}}, connectionPoolSettings=ConnectionPoolSettings{maxSize=100, minSize=0, maxWaitTimeMS=120000, maxConnectionLifeTimeMS=0, maxConnectionIdleTimeMS=0, maintenanceInitialDelayMS=0, maintenanceFrequencyMS=60000, connectionPoolListeners=[], maxConnecting=2}, serverSettings=ServerSettings{heartbeatFrequencyMS=10000, minHeartbeatFrequencyMS=500, serverListeners='[]', serverMonitorListeners='[]'}, sslSettings=SslSettings{enabled=false, invalidHostNameAllowed=false, context=null}, applicationName='null', compressorList=[], uuidRepresentation=JAVA_LEGACY, serverApi=null, autoEncryptionSettings=null, dnsClient=null, inetAddressResolver=null, contextProvider=null}
2023-12-31T11:54:11.107Z  INFO 36867 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=21, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=1434541}
2023-12-31T11:54:11.111Z  INFO 36867 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2023-12-31T11:54:11.155Z DEBUG 36867 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : 10 mappings in 'requestMappingHandlerMapping'
2023-12-31T11:54:11.164Z DEBUG 36867 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Patterns [/webjars/**, /**, /swagger-ui*/*swagger-initializer.js, /swagger-ui*/**] in 'resourceHandlerMapping'
2023-12-31T11:54:11.167Z DEBUG 36867 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : ControllerAdvice beans: 0 @ModelAttribute, 0 @InitBinder, 1 RequestBodyAdvice, 1 ResponseBodyAdvice
2023-12-31T11:54:11.168Z DEBUG 36867 --- [  restartedMain] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : ControllerAdvice beans: 1 @ExceptionHandler, 1 ResponseBodyAdvice
2023-12-31T11:54:11.200Z  WARN 36867 --- [  restartedMain] org.jline                                : Unable to create a system terminal, creating a dumb terminal (enable debug logging for more information)
2023-12-31T11:54:11.224Z  INFO 36867 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-12-31T11:54:11.226Z  INFO 36867 --- [  restartedMain] c.i.investorapi.InvestorapiApplication   : Started InvestorapiApplication in 0.281 seconds (process running for 40.859)
shell:>help
No command found for 'hl'
shell:>
```

Just tried Eclipse as well - same issue.

Comment: Did you `enable debug logging for more information` as the message suggests?

Comment: @JimGarrison Yes, I've tried enabling debug, but didn't see any helpful info there: